# How to generate serialVersionUID-like id for a Java Class at runtime?

Tags: java, serialization

I'd like to generate an Id for a given Java Class by inspecting its field names, types, and all other components of the class that play a role during serialization and deserialization, not necessarily Java serialization as it could be Json, etc.

The id generation should be repeatable and deterministic unless there's a change in a field type or some other component of the class. I think I could recursively traverse the class and generate something like it but I didn't want to do it unless there's no other way.

I read that Java applies a complex procedure to determine serialVersionUID if none is declared. It considers class members, its super interfaces, etc. It seemed similar but I'd like to generate ids for ***non-Serializable*** classes as well.

My use-case is that I'm storing Java object(s) in an external datastore and I'd like to incorporate this runtime-generated id in the key to handle non-backward compatible changes gracefully.

Comment: Eclipse can generate it automatically at compile time. Why do you need it to be generated at runtime?

Comment: The use-case is slightly different. It's not quite `serialVersionUID` that I'm looking for. I'd like something similar and something that's not maintained by class author(s).

Comment: The algorithm for computing a serialVersionUID is described at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#a4100 .  You don’t have to follow it exactly, of course, but it is important that the fields and methods are sorted, as reflection methods like Class.getFields() do not guarantee the order in which members are returned.

Comment: @VGR Thanks. I will go through the algo to see if I can implement something similar. Are you aware of any libraries that could do this?

Comment: Only ObjectStreamClass, I’m afraid.  I have not seen anything which will do it for a non-Serializable class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get exactly the `serialVersionUID` of any class whether the field is present or not, via [`ObjectStreamClass.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html#forClass--)[`.getSerialVersionUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html#getSerialVersionUID--).

Comment: Thanks for response. I'd like to be able to generate an id/md5/sha for a non-Serializable class as well (some might be using just json-based serialization). Just updated the question to make that requirement prominent.

Comment: @phani did you notice [`ObjectStreamClass.lookupAny(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html#lookupAny-java.lang.Class-)? It is supposed to give a `ObjectStreamClass` for non-serializable classes as well.

Comment: It's been a while. So I do not remember if I had seen this. However FYI, I ended up implementing a custom "id" creator for a given class. It just appends class name, method signatures in the class, etc. into 1 large string and then hashes that string.

Comment: Btw, the API doesn't seem to work as expected. I created a non-serializable class Person and used that API. The response was "static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;"